# Why does my code skip over input from users?

Tags: c, debugging

So this is some code I have written, I am barley beginning on c so bear with me, my code makes sense to me but its not working properly, when am trying to say no to stop playing and display average it repeats the playing function.

Basically my program guesses the users number from 1-100 whatever number the user came up with. Here's some output that is wrong, just to give you an idea. The play game function is working fine but not the main.

```
Playing guess my number game 

is your number 50 ?=
Great!
Play again? (y for yes n for no): is your number 50 ?=
Great!
Play again? (y for yes n for no): is your number 50 ?n
```

and so on  i cant find where i went wrong any advice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int playgame(void);
main() {
   int numberofplays = 0;
   float average = 0;
   int numberguesses = 0;

   printf("Playing guess my number game\n");
   printf("-------------------------------\n");
   bool play = true;
   int xtry = 0;
   int totaltries = 0;
   char answer;
   do {
       xtry = playgame();
       numberofplays++;
       totaltries = totaltries + xtry;
       printf("Play again? (y for yes n for no): ");
       answer = getchar();
       if(answer =='n')
                play = false;

    } while(play==true);

    average = (float)(totaltries/numberofplays);
    printf("average is %f tries per game\n",average);
    return 0;
} 
int playgame(void) {
    int guessnumber = 50;
    int xnumber = 25;
    int count=0;
    char x;
    bool stillguessing = true;

    while(stillguessing == true) {
        printf("is your number %d ?", guessnumber);
        x = getchar();

        if(x=='=') {
            count++;
            printf("Great!\n");
            stillguessing=false;
            return count;
        }
        else if(x == '<') {
            guessnumber = guessnumber - xnumber;
            xnumber = xnumber/2;
            if(xnumber<1) xnumber = 1;
            count++;
        }
        else if (x == '>') {
             guessnumber = guessnumber +xnumber;
             xnumber = xnumber/2;
             if(xnumber<1) xnumber = 1;
             count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using `<stdbool.h>`, you must be using C99, and therefore you should write an explicit return type for `main()`, either `int main(void)` or — at a pinch — `int main()`, assuming no command-line argument processing.  This won't directly affect the behaviour of your program, but it should affect the compiler warnings (if it doesn't, you aren't using enough of them).

Comment: For the closers; I don't think this question warrants closing... maybe an edit. The question is legitimate and common... a lack of understanding of the way that streams work leads many novice programmers to this kind of error... thus this question is useful.

Answer (score 2):

The function `getchar` pulls a character from the stream `stdin`.

The stream `stdin` contains everything that you have entered into the Standard Input device; in your case, this is the keyboard.

Now, when you respond to the computer's guess, you press two keys. You press <kbd>=</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Your code in `playgame` handles the <kbd>=</kbd>, but it leaves the <kbd>Enter</kbd> on `stdin`... thus, your next call to `getchar` pulls that.

What you need to do is to flush the `stdin` stream. You can't use [`fflush(stdin)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) for this, as `fflush` is for output streams.

Instead, you can use something like

```
void flushSTDIN() {
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}
```

to clear out any old newlines in the buffer, before you ask your question.

You should do this before all calls to `getchar` in your program.

So:

```
flushSTDIN();
printf("is your number %d ?", guessnumber);
x = getchar();
```

Comment: While your reasoning is correct, `fflush(stdin)` is *undefined behaviour*. May be, another `getchar()` right after the first one, wherever needed, to consume the newline can solve the problem..

Comment: @KingsIndian: thanks; modifications made.

Comment: Note that on Windows, `fflush(stdin)` has implementation-defined behaviour.  On other platforms, it is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `getchar()` is consuming a single character from the input. However, the input stream always contains at least two characters when you enter a response: the character you enter (such as `'='`) and the newline (or enter) character that follows it.

This does not matter so much in the `playgame()` function (although all of the prompts are printed twice), but when you get to

```
answer = getchar();
```

this call to `getchar()` gets the newline that was left over from the previous character you typed.

How you fix this is a question of how you want to handle user input - whether you want to validate it, whether you want to be able to enter longer strings, etc.

In your case, the simplest solution is to replace your calls to `getchar()` with a loop that will discard whitespace.

I suggest doing the following:

Add the following line at (or near) the start of your program:

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

This provides the `isspace()` function that cleanly and portably checks if a character is whitespace.

Replace the line:

```
answer = getchar();
```

with:

```
while (isspace(answer = getchar()))
    ;
```

And similarly, replace

```
x = getchar();
```

with:

```
while (isspace(x = getchar()))
    ;
```

The single semicolon is a [null statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7zyw61x.aspx) - *something* (in this case nothing) has to go in the body of the loop.

Assigning to `x`/`answer` within a condition would often be frowned upon, but in this particular case it is the most idiomatic way of writing this.

Note that incorrect macro implementations of `isspace()` could cause issues by evaluating the call to `getchar()` [multiple times](http://cse.spsu.edu/teidson/Languages/cpp/Duplication-of-Side-Effects.html#Duplication-of-Side-Effects)